# How to reset multiple select to its first value in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a select which contains options, I want to be able to resent each of the select to its first value onclick

```js
$('.reset').on('click', function() {
  $('food option:first').prop('selected', true);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
  <select class="food">
    <option value="" selected disabled>Select Food</option>
    <option value="rice">Rice</option>
    <option value="garri">Garri</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" class="showfood">
  <button class="reset">Reset Select</button>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <select class="food">
    <option value="" selected disabled>Select Food</option>
    <option value="beans">Beans</option>
    <option value="pear">pear</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" class="showfood">
  <button class="reset">Reset Select</button>
</div>
```

However, what this does is reset only the first select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic to reset is correct. The issue you have is that you need to find only the `option` related to the `select` within the same container as the clicked button. To achieve that you can use `closest()` and `find()`, like this:

```js
$('.reset').on('click', function() {
  $(this).closest('.box').find('.food option:first').prop('selected', true);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
  <select class="food">
    <option value="" selected disabled>Select Food</option>
    <option value="rice">Rice</option>
    <option value="garri">Garri</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" class="showfood">
  <button class="reset">Reset Select</button>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <select class="food">
    <option value="" selected disabled>Select Food</option>
    <option value="beans">Beans</option>
    <option value="pear">pear</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" class="showfood">
  <button class="reset" type="button">Reset Select</button>
</div>
```